# Android device with os 2.3.3 powers the attached camera and access the pen drive content

Tags: android, usb

Android has USB accessory or host mode in 2.3.4, 3.1 and higher versions.

But when I use Android 2.3.3 or 2.2, I can power the connected camera and also can access pen drive content.

Why is this happening and then? Is it just the library that we have in some of the versions and nothing about the internal hardware?

If not about internal hardware than is it possible to create our own driver for all version to have the device in host mode?

Answer (score 0):

Android itself support host mode in almost all recent versions. So you can connect keyboard, mouse, usb-drive, etc to a android device. This is done on system level, but not exposed to user's apps.

In Android 2.3.3 (api level 10) was added interfaces to access usb device from userspace. So now you can write app that communicates with an usb device.

Technically, you can write JNI wrapper for libusb, and use host functionality in earlier Android releases, but there are many pitfalls, so I don't recommend you to do this.

Comment: i thought it was added in 2.3.4, any way can you please tell me the package i should use in my 2.3.3 code. Thanks.